# Rewrite an equation with partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do you rewrite $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{f}$ in terms of new variables $u$ and $v$, where $u=2x-f^2$ and $v=-y/f$?

Assume that $f(x,y)$ is a function, and the answer should at most contain $u,v,f,f_u,f_v.$

An answer of $v(f^2-u)f_v=f(f^2+u)$ is provided for the problem.

Comment: The potential problems start when we identify $f(x,y)$ with $f(u,v)$ instead of giving that a new name $g(u,v)\,.$ There will be a very good chance that you can find the answer yourself when you observe my hint.

Comment: I've managed to find a solution without introducing a function $g$. However, it's very bulky, so it'd be useful to see what steps an as-efficient-as-possible solution might take.

Comment: The method of characteristics straightaway gives $f^2=2x+F(y/x)$ where $F$ is an arbitrary fonction to be determined according to some boundary condition. No need for change of variable.